# spring.profiles.active not being honored from command line, but works in IDE

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, spring-profiles

At a bit of a loss here. I have a sample application/proof-of-concept that I am trying to get to work with the following configuration:

Layer 1: library that utilizes Spring components, to be hidden away from end user libraries/applications.

Layer 2: library that pulls in the aforementioned library, but is otherwise non-Spring implemented. Smart enough to auto-establish the Spring context, but hide the details of this from users of the library.

Layer 3: application that uses the "middleware" library in layer 2, also non-Spring aware.

I have all of this working as I expect, even being able to set the active profile (spring.profiles.active) and have the correct properties file be picked up from the classpath of the Layer 3 application. Here's the oddity:

If I run the application from my IDE (IntelliJ) and have it pass the active profile on the command line, all works as expected. The values I load from my "production" properties file override those in the default properties file. That is, value of key X in `application-production.properties` overrides the value of X in `application.properties`.

All good, right? Ok, try to run the jar from the command line doing the same thing (`java -Dspring.profiles.active=production -jar my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar`). I see in the debug log that the "production" properties file is picked up, but the default file is being given precedence. That is, the value in `application.properties` is being used, even though the Spring context clearly states that "production" is active, and it finds and loads `application-production.properties` just fine.

Eh, WAT?!

Has anyone else experienced this, and if so, any workaround? I'm pulling in Spring IO Platform Brussels-SR5, which includes version 4.3.11.RELEASE of spring-core, spring-context, et al. The jar for the application is a shaded jar that contains all dependencies. The two library jars are not shaded.

**EDIT**

Log is rather long ... going to try and snip to the relevant parts ...

```
william@jessie:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app$ java -Dspring.profiles.active=production -jar example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar 
20:20:18.726 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'systemProperties' with lowest search precedence
20:20:18.732 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'systemEnvironment' with lowest search precedence
20:20:18.733 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [MapPropertySource@20557198 {name='systemProperties', properties={java.runtime.name=OpenJDK Runtime Environment, sun.boot.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386, java.vm.version=25.141-b15, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, path.separator=:, java.vm.name=OpenJDK Server VM, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, user.country=US, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, sun.os.patch.level=unknown, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, user.dir=/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app, java.runtime.version=1.8.0_141-8u141-b15-1~deb9u1-b15, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment, java.endorsed.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/endorsed, os.arch=i386, spring.profiles.active=production, java.io.tmpdir=/tmp, line.separator=
, java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, os.name=Linux, sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8, java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib, java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, java.class.version=52.0, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot Tiered Compilers, os.version=4.9.0-3-686-pae, user.home=/home/william, user.timezone=America/New_York, java.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob, file.encoding=UTF-8, java.specification.version=1.8, java.class.path=example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar, user.name=william, java.vm.specification.version=1.8, sun.java.command=example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar, java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre, sun.arch.data.model=32, user.language=en, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, awt.toolkit=sun.awt.X11.XToolkit, java.vm.info=mixed mode, java.version=1.8.0_141, java.ext.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext, sun.boot.class.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/classes, java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, file.separator=/, java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle, sun.cpu.endian=little, sun.cpu.isalist=}}, SystemEnvironmentPropertySource@5592464 {name='systemEnvironment', properties={ .. truncated ..}}]
20:20:18.765 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Resolved classpath location [tech/chihuahua/examples/] to resources [URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/]]
20:20:18.767 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar]
20:20:18.786 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Resolved location pattern [classpath*:tech/chihuahua/examples/**/*.class] to resources [URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/client/GreetingClient.class], URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/client/GreetingClientImpl.class], URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/client/GreetingClientFactory.class], URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/config/LibraryProductionContext.class], URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/config/LibraryStagingContext.class], URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/config/LibraryDefaultContext.class], URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/config/LibraryIntegrationTestContext.class], URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/config/LibraryProductionContext$ProductionProperties.class], URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/config/LibraryIntegrationTestContext$IntegrationTestProperties.class], URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/config/LibraryStagingContext$StagingProperties.class], URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/config/LibraryDefaultContext$DefaultProperties.class], URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/Profiles.class], URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/LibraryContextProvider.class], URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/service/GreetingService.class]]
20:20:18.825 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/config/LibraryProductionContext.class]
20:20:18.825 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/config/LibraryStagingContext.class]
20:20:18.831 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/config/LibraryDefaultContext.class]
20:20:18.832 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/config/LibraryIntegrationTestContext.class]
20:20:18.840 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'spring.profiles.active' in PropertySource 'systemProperties' with value of type String
20:20:18.840 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/config/LibraryProductionContext$ProductionProperties.class]
20:20:18.842 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/config/LibraryDefaultContext$DefaultProperties.class]
20:20:18.845 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/service/GreetingService.class]
20:20:18.858 [main] INFO org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@16f64b1: startup date [Thu Oct 05 20:20:18 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
20:20:18.858 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Bean factory for org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@16f64b1: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1629756: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,libraryProductionContext,libraryStagingContext,libraryDefaultContext,libraryIntegrationTestContext,libraryProductionContext.ProductionProperties,libraryDefaultContext.DefaultProperties,greetingService]; root of factory hierarchy
20:20:18.883 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
20:20:18.883 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
20:20:18.902 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
20:20:18.904 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
20:20:18.930 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'class path resource [application-production.properties]' with lowest search precedence
20:20:18.936 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'class path resource [application.properties]' with search precedence immediately higher than 'class path resource [application-production.properties]'
20:20:18.938 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Resolved classpath location [tech/chihuahua/examples/] to resources [URL [jar:file:/mnt/builds/william/src/mixed-spring-legacy-app/example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar!/tech/chihuahua/examples/]]
```

So, you can see here that the profile-specific properties file is being set to lower priority than the catch-all properties file. Also,

```
20:20:19.128 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'greetingService' to allow for resolving potential circular references
20:20:19.128 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected element of bean 'greetingService': AutowiredMethodElement for public void tech.chihuahua.examples.service.GreetingService.setEnvironment(org.springframework.core.env.Environment)
20:20:19.130 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'environment'
20:20:19.130 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - Autowiring by type from bean name 'greetingService' to bean named 'environment'
    Active profile: production
20:20:19.179 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'tech.chihuahua.examples.greeting.format' in PropertySource 'class path resource [application.properties]' with value of type String
    tech.chihuahua.examples.greeting.format set to 'Hi, %s!'
20:20:19.179 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'greetingService'
20:20:19.179 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer'
20:20:19.180 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
20:20:19.210 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@1afa13b]
20:20:19.210 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
20:20:19.212 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source
20:20:19.214 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'greetingService'
20:20:19.214 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'tech.chihuahua.examples.greeting.format' in PropertySource 'class path resource [application.properties]' with value of type String
Hi, Jack!
```

Where I actually invoke the bean, I added code to show what profile is active, and what the property value contains.

As I said previously, this works correctly when running from my IDE, but not from the jar file.

**EDIT #2**

So I tried removing the properties files from the jar and running with them in the current directory. Same result. Dumped the jar out to a folder, added the properties files to that folder ... works like it is supposed to. So it is definitely something to do with the jar in the mix.

Comment: As an aside, I have tried restarting my IDE, restarting my machine, etc, just in case it was having some kind of brain-cramp, but to no avail. Also, I am not using Spring Boot in the layer 1 library since it, while making use of Spring, needs to be as small as I can make it, and Boot tends to pull in a lot of additional dependencies that are of no use to me.

Comment: Can you post the actual log?

Answer (score 2):

So I finally came up with a workaround to this. As for why it was working with all of the classes/properties files in a folder and not when inside the jar, the best answer I can give is "purple, because aliens don't wear hats."

At any rate, what I had to do was to add another "profiled" properties class that is specific for the "default" profile. That would receive whatever was in the "application-default.properties" file, and would only be activated if no other profiles were activated. The "application.properties" file should contain no data that would be overridden based on active profile.

Code example for how this works ...

***Catch-all/root configuration***

```
package tech.chihuahua.examples.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import tech.chihuahua.examples.service.GreetingService;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("tech.chihuahua.examples")
public class LibraryContext {

    @Configuration
    @PropertySources({
            @PropertySource(
                    value = "${spring.config.location}/application.properties",
                    ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
            @PropertySource(
                    value = "classpath:application.properties",
                    ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
    })
    static class ApplicationProperties {}

    @Bean
    GreetingService greetingService() {
        return new GreetingService();
    }

    @Bean
    static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

***Defaults, for when no profile is active***

```
package tech.chihuahua.examples.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;

@Configuration
public class LibraryDefaultContext {

    @Profile("default")
    @Configuration
    @PropertySources({
            @PropertySource(
                    value = "${spring.config.location}/application-default.properties",
                    ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
            @PropertySource(
                    value = "classpath:application-default.properties",
                    ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
    })
    static class DefaultProperties {}

}
```

***Production profile active***

```
package tech.chihuahua.examples.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;
import tech.chihuahua.examples.Profiles;

@Configuration
public class LibraryProductionContext {

    @Profile(Profiles.PRODUCTION)
    @Configuration
    @PropertySources({
            @PropertySource(
                    value = "${spring.config.location}/application-production.properties",
                    ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
            @PropertySource(
                    value = "classpath:application-production.properties",
                    ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
    })
    static class ProductionProperties {}

}
```

***Staging profile active***

```
package tech.chihuahua.examples.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;
import tech.chihuahua.examples.Profiles;

@Configuration
public class LibraryStagingContext {

    @Profile(Profiles.STAGING)
    @Configuration
    @PropertySources({
            @PropertySource(
                    value = "${spring.config.location}/application-staging.properties",
                    ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
            @PropertySource(
                    value = "classpath:application-staging.properties",
                    ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
    })
    static class StagingProperties {}

}
```

With all that in place, build the uber-jar. Include the properties files in the jar, if so desired, or make sure they are available in a folder on your machine (e.g. /etc/my-app).

```
# The general application configuration settings go here.
/etc/my-app/application.properties

# The default configuration settings go here
# (e.g. configure the application to use an in-memory database)
/etc/my-app/application-default.properties

# The production configuration settings go here
# (e.g. configure the application to use your production database)
/etc/my-app/application-production.properties

# The staging configuration settings go here
# (e.g. configure the application to use a staging/test database)
/etc/my-app/application-staging.properties
```

***Execute the app with the default settings***

Spring will automatically set the "default" profile to be active if no other profiles are specified. So here, the "application-default.properties" file will be picked up, and its configuration will be used.

```
# Using the properties files in the classpath in the jar
java -jar my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar

# Using the properties files on the file system
java -Dspring.config.location=file:///etc/my-app \
     -jar my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar
```

***Execute the app with the production profile active***

By enabling the "production" profile, the "default" profile will not be activated. Thus, "application-default.properties" is ignored, and "application-production.properties" is loaded.

```
# Using the properties files in the classpath in the jar
java -Dspring.profiles.active=production \
     -jar my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar

# Using the properties files on the file system
java -Dspring.profiles.active=production \
     -Dspring.config.location=file:///etc/my-app \
     -jar my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar
```

***Execute the app with the staging profile active***

Same as previous, just using the "staging" profile instead of "production".

```
# Using the properties files in the classpath in the jar
java -Dspring.profiles.active=staging \
     -jar my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar

# Using the properties files on the file system
java -Dspring.profiles.active=staging \
     -Dspring.config.location=file:///etc/my-app \
     -jar my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar
```

Hoping this helps save someone time and aggravation.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the property name in quotes as given below and try.  This should work:

```
java -D"spring.profiles.active"=production -jar example-app/target/example-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-full.jar
```

Please confirm if the suggested change solve the issue.